# Is there a way to change the output format of a Map in Java?

Tags: java

I need to print out a map just by using System.out.println in a certain format, without using 'while' or 'for'.

I have to print out a map  that looks like

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

using System.out.println(map);

But now it looks like

```
{a=1, b=2, c=3}
```

What should I do?

Comment: You could write your own `Map` class (maybe a subclass of `HashMap` so that you don't have to rewrite the usual methods), and provide your own implementation of `toString`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to just print it like this.

```
map.forEach((k,v)->System.out.printf("%s %s", k,v));
```

The other way is to override toString when you create the map.

```
Map<String,Double> map = new HashMap<>() {
   public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(Entry<?,?> e : this.entrySet()) {
           sb.append(e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue());
        }
        return sb.toString();
   }
};
```

Then you can just do

```
System.out.println(map);
```

But I would still do it the first way.  No need to override toString when printing a map is easy using the enhanced for loop.  And I don't really like overriding API methods unless there is a really good reason to do so.

Comment: I think one of the requirements is to not use `for`. I would imagine if this is a homework assignment that the teacher probably meant no looping, which forEach kinda does.

Comment: Well, they gotta loop somewhere.